# Can a computer learn strategies of a game by analyzing others' game?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm wondering if there is any reinforcement learning technique capable of learning how to play a game and some strategies from it simply by analyzing matches played by others instead of playing it himself.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `python` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods when strategy is learned using moves not generated by the learning strategy itself are usually called **off-policy learning** methods and they are widely studied together with **on-policy learning** methods (these ones are referring to the situation when learning algorithm is generating the moves itself).

There are tons of information about off-policy learning methods here and on other sources.

A good example of off-policy methods is [Q-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning). While examples of on-policy methods would be direct policy gradient methods (such as REINFORCE algorithm and its variations like A3C, etc.)

When I was first looking in reinforcement learning area these two articles helped me a lot: [RL article with high level overview of popular algorithms](https://medium.com/@SmartLabAI/reinforcement-learning-algorithms-an-intuitive-overview-904e2dff5bbc), [Policy gradients lecture](http://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse-fa17/f17docs/lecture_4_policy_gradient.pdf).